# Show that $19^{31}>13^{33}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, number-comparison

> How can i prove that $19^{31}>13^{33}$?

What I tried

$$\bigg(\frac{19}{13}\bigg)^2=\frac{361}{169}>2>1$$
then $19^{2}>13^{2}$ and $\displaystyle 19^{30}>13^{30}$

How do I show it. Help me please.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that by the binomial theorem
$$\left(\frac{19}{13}\right)^{31}=\left(1+\frac{6}{13}\right)^{31}>\binom{31}{3}\frac{6^3}{13^3}=\frac{31\cdot 30\cdot 29\cdot 36}{13^3}>\frac{26^4}{13^3}=16\cdot 13>13^2$$
which implies that $19^{31}>13^{33}$.

**Bonus question**. By using a similar approach we can show the stronger inequality $19^{31}>13^{34}$. Would you like to try it?

Comment: Solved bonus below(before seeing it posted).

Answer (score 6):

$$A=19^{31}\geq 19^{16}\cdot18^{15} = \color{red}{19^{16}\cdot 9^{15}} \cdot  2^{15}$$

$$B=13^{33} = 13\cdot 169^{16}\leq 13\cdot 171^{16} = 13 \cdot \color{red}{19^{16}\cdot 9^{15}}\cdot 9$$

Clearly  $$2^{15}\geq 13\cdot 9\implies A>B$$

Answer (score 4):

Just compute the minimum $x$ such that $19^x > 13^{x+2}$. By taking logarithm on both sides, we have
$x \ln(19) > (x+2) \ln(13)$ 
and finally
$ x > 2 \frac{\ln(13)}{\ln(\frac{19}{13})}$ and the number on the right is smaller than 13 so way smaller than the case $x = 31$.

Comment: How do you know it is less than 13?

Comment: $\ln(\tfrac{19}{13}) = \ln(1+ \tfrac{6}{13}) \simeq \frac{6}{13}$ by Taylor expansion. Then $\ln(13) \le \ln(e^3)$ because $e^3 \ge (2.7)^3$ and $2.7^3 = 2^3 + 12*(0.7)^2 + ... \ge 15$ (by using the identity for $(a+b)^3$. 
You get $\ln(13)/\ln(1+6/13) \le \frac{13 \ln(e^3)}{6} = 39/6 = 6.5$ and with the $2$ in front you get the announced 13.
To be honest I thought the original goal was just to reduce the complexity for this computation to be solved by say a middle school calculator, but it turns out it is easy to justify the bound that I gave.

Answer (score 4):

By your work
$$\frac{19^2}{13^2}>2,$$ which says
$$\left(\frac{19}{13}\right)^{31}>2^{15.5}>2^8=256>13^2$$ and we are done!

By this way we can prove that
$$19^{31}>13^{35}.$$

Answer (score 2):

$19^{30}=(19^3)^{10}=6859^{10}\gt 13^{30}=(13^3)^{10}=2197^{10}$

$6859\gt 3\times 2197=6591$

$6859^{10}\gt (3\times 2197)^{10}=3^{10}\times 2197^{10}=3^3\times 3^3\times 3^3\times 3\times 2197^{10}=27^3\times 3\times 2197^{10}$

$27^3\times 3\times 2197^{10}\gt 13^3\times 2197^{10}$ already without even multiplying by $19.$

Answer (score 2):

$\left[\dfrac{19}{13}\right]^{\large 4}\!\!\!=\!\left[1\!+\!\dfrac{6}{13}\right]^{\large 4}\!\!>1\!+\!4\left[\dfrac{6}{13}\right]\!>2\,\overset{(\ \ \,)^{\LARGE 8}}\Longrightarrow\, \left[\dfrac{19}{13}\right]^{\large 32}\!\!\!>2^{\large 8} > 19\cdot 13$

Answer (score 1):

Well, using what you've got so far:

$(\frac {19}{13})^2 > 2$ so $(\frac {19}{13})^{30} > 2^{15}$  so $19^{30} > 2^{15}*13^{30}$.

$19^{31} = 19^{30} *19 > 13^{30}*(19*2^{15}) {? \over >} 13^{30}*13^3 = 13^{33}$.  If we can show $19*(2^{15}) > 13^3$ we will be done.

=====

For what it's worth one way I might do it if it were up to me is to note.

$19 > 13$ so $19^k > 13^k$  For $19^k > 13^{k+2} = 13^k *13^2$ we need $(\frac {19}{13})^k > 169$.

$(\frac {19}{13})^2 > 2$ so $(\frac {19}{13})^{16} > 2^8 = 256> 169$.

So $19^{16} > 13^{18}$ and $19^{31} > 13^{33}$.... by a *lot*.